# Get UseStaticFiles() to point http://example.com/myfile to /wwwroot/myfile.{environment}.js

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I want to be able to change the url to a static file in my wwwroot without changing the filename. F.ex I want to be able to go to www.mysite.com/myfile and it would get the randomotherfile.js in the wwwroot.

Basicly this is an example of what I want to be able to do, but the physicalfileprovider only takes directories.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
       Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot", $"myfile.{env.EnvironmentName}.js")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/superfile") 
        });
```

in this case www.mysite.com/superfile would get me f.ex myfile.test.js.

Using .net core 1.1

Comment: You're probably better off with a rewrite rule instead of messing with the static file middleware. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting

Comment: @DavidG Thanks, will check it out